# Integrate using Composite Simpson's rule

Tags: numerics

In a question, we have been given the speed of a car at time t= 0,2,4,6,.......,20 minutes.But it asks us to approximate the distance travelled by the car in 30 minutes using Composite
Simpson's rule.  I do not understand how that can be done as so far I have come across problems where I have been asked to approximate till the given data points.But this question asks us to extrapolate. Any help on how to go about it.

Comment: It may help to just write out the whole problem statement. This could make clear what assumptions are expected in determining an answer

Answer (score 0):

The displacement of the car is given as the integral of the car velocity + the initial displacement.
Consequently, if you do not have data points covering the 0 to 30 minutes range (velocity at 0min and one at 30min), there are no ways to calculate the displacement. Maybe the problem is implicitly assuming that the velocity remains constant from 20 mins to 30 mins?

Comment: I suspect a typo, either in the homework assignment, or the question asked here. If you have no data outside your time range, then you can not integrate.

Comment: I was then unnecessarily worried about it.